# HTTP handlers problems

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler

I'm a newbie when it comes to HTTP handlers and i'm struggling to work out what the problemis with my current code

I seem to be getting this error

> Class 'Handler' must implement 'Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)' for interface 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'.

When using this code

```
    <%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="Handler" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Handler

    Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext)
Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim con As New SqlConnection(connStr)

        ' Create SQL Command 

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from My_Images" +
                          " where id =@id"
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con

        Dim ImageID As New SqlParameter("@investor", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        ImageID.Value = context.Request.QueryString("id")
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageID)
        con.Open()
        Dim dReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dReader.Read()
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(DirectCast(dReader("Image"), Byte()))
        dReader.Close()
        con.Close()
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable As Boolean _
        Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable

            Get
                Return True
            End Get
        End Property

End Class
```

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your method declaration is wrong.
This should do it:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)
```

MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ihttphandler.isreusable.aspx

Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

The method declaration

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext)
```

should be

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest`

You will also need implements on the IsReusable property.